# When can I access instance variables of init method?

Tags: python-2.7

Why I cannot access instance variables g of mnc method?

```
class yy(object):
    k="suri"
    def __init__(self,a,b):
         self.h="amruth"
         print a
         print b
    def mnc(self,x):
        self.g="tamu"
        yy.k="yyy"
m=yy('gg','yy')
print m.h
print m.g
```

Comment: ...what? You never call the `mnc` method, so the `g` instance attribute never gets defined and the `k` class attribute never gets updated. Why is that surprising?

Comment: Please don't downvote my question

Comment: Users can vote how they please - improve the question following the guidance in [ask] if you don't like the outcome.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Y do they say that accessing instance variables is evil.

Comment: I don't know who *"they"* are in this context.

Comment: class intSet(object):
 #An intSet is a set of integers
 def __init__(self):
 """Create an empty set of integers""" t
 self.numBuckets = 47
 self.vals = []
 for i in range(self.numBuckets):
 self.vals.append([]). in this code a professor says it its not good to access object.vals.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't just keep adding pointless comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call/invoke 'mnc' method first before access 'g'

```
m=yy('gg','yy')
m.mnc('some value')
print m.h
print m.g
```